# How to remove status bar transparency in IOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I want to remove status bar transparency [image]
here what i have tried so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
        self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not remove it. Do not *want* to remove it. The status bar *is* transparent. Accept the facts and work with them, not against them.

If you want the status bar area to look green, put something green behind it. It would be better, however, to use a navigation controller and navigation bar, which *automatically* extends its drawing behind the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add subview on top of the status bar using `statusBarManager`.

In ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame {
            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
            view.addSubview(statusBarView)
            statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Else in SceneDelegate:

```
let statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
statusBarView.backgroundColor = .green
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to change background for status bar

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    let statusBarView =  UIView()
    statusBarView.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
}
```